# Get XML tag value using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new at using xsl. I need to transform the following SOAP ws response. I have the following XML input:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:NS1="urn:ECGTSIncomingSoapWebServiceIntf-IIncomingWebService" xmlns:NS2="urn:unECGIncomingSoapGlobal">
    <NS1:RequestResponse>
        <return href="#1"/>
    </NS1:RequestResponse>
    <NS2:TECGIncomingResponse id="1" xsi:type="NS2:TECGIncomingResponse">
        <Error xsi:type="xsd:int">0</Error>
        <ErrorMsg xsi:type="xsd:string"></ErrorMsg>
        <Output xsi:type="xsd:string">2VKFKup1ZWNs0yCmDMCW/xXNwNHGb1hrVP7MilsECKpUrZWv4UfHJ6Nvi9kun7bdig/YwaOUVmSSVq1syKkdP08zGuZaoGHBBjsmR+zrPt5Ppo/govH7yyynLSfkIbBI/tNzwW6BtND+Dz0750ybm0pI6TQbyN2aKzTUB0Zj8FGXE/sAllTD19xeFIhqOBT5s5/zMZXWoaBoi5yhnsAFSqHhdTmZ2urFUc2m2t7nPNAmZze48+1b/xItDTZoybus+ZXDMRivr5ZxkjkaCGhcIvBoqHc0APYPMNg3YnwEhdw1DxDqilFx1FFR/6O0ntcKRN4luR7vzxnB/WH5gRXCT7WAhxIZn6Aa2Mfjf+FWMrr/Kr9jpeSiLlRsogA/83Cvv9xSzNHepRpKLNYXQfvW+ps8O7paPcPpA3Hp6Ajob3E3T3l6t2olGLfvwINlDgSQiV2+XdDrCONxSESboCuZUzxN1dVKWNdWl3rOwKK1xDazORX2sOtHnofp7exTH9e3/tqEUHBC4CVeYns6He4mm1+gilHYlLSDwn6NUrA1O0Hk8QRVUOoF5Symz62/DAHlr7GUbrC30AchGFB6qu98PxBenQVo7oJND1gIAi/jIzEaesDc/EvtBTvrjL6TgW5q6xBxFZghgeUuFU3sM+z+lG561bBn6xbv/PbvPNiycjPvRLp5jvBmmRr6dJJyYx9L7Zjx1WkZWFT14rqwsAnodKjWCJjaojNK0tkhboO+UIohygShTNhgYTFgtlUXft9d0kVZajsvotadC6jOobDPWI5nuQNBhHPjmxHdOYKdAwPChgCa0bDWF0VO6Fpqux5JJTwmsK6Cs036FUaqxbJllsymj0AmjgoBzair0oCm/u8PK4iQjvR9lRqQyiPvQl9/bOZ4oWM9Jo7eIyKjI3DCidJfO2C+5Fz3EC2b3Hx9ofnvjkiHZWlAlClEpHYWLY3KrinkTo9vOgCpqnqQBk1K5qnuZZ0818OopOmk747aNh+7pYAbzx80z16YsS88mf4j/RYeI1mABYWHOx720boVdWCmooLfagboTCuuuIlT/RrMShaaIA4AGyTNKV2W0tBK20BGVExXWn/WdDXfVymGPVuajJAnwx5pYEOPAfgAH96YOczZ17zL119YmMFIFIaFTJyHPCpuvUZJX3ZT/pSCp6yaJ1DlW54tKT9ljSirapwyIiXQXvukqydeRoW0Hkq45EraFeSzS5OoakeER1Fl0HAXOiVza1gm/7Byp6zJjnumzchfX8++nKlwABT9R8fgh6C1pBjePwT1DQC0zDQrJUXsow5KU0NQpQDK1dCV7oUnwfn1rcS/BSWsG8Czox3ueA69+oTYov9gsxS5h/rRLUy2l8bMcw+iJZt5OKxpQZK28F0NSfZSOgdc7QgvSe3kpAbSdcssXtwDWqJ0QwS9EpBP3eUNuv4/sDOSsJFa0+IkbcHHA31Bnbn9PRJqRtNq5kUkgBX334iyXNyEFuTU7XGfYCyL7RR3ZlLCwURYMFKQxp/7WjglBRS9VXYFbJ1MBHFsFvom1llqUB91uE6WVCaCIXKarQ4R9nfcyePw6V2WjmPwM2B9bbbtMLkDWpVw8ztt72wkggqFt2n4E9+xjbPiyPzImD5QrUp9qRw8Qw/NSeUYQXf+wb2oIcsK80kN0zM2Qnz69Nqjo4+XlFpGQMJk3u2M3SbOQPT929rQZxtu9yQPw1Dy1xeCr/KzaYofgAMOlIfAznfY4XJi1XuK5A+3DC/kGVORLEme/eiplY5R36BZlcMt5G3xrYjk7t1wmwVD5B7KLzTkADyUYU+m7zk+MXbsb9GScetFELf2ENp93JZ7alnVXR0yYJ77R9KKvvg59owAAml68eCY3rJGZ8RYyfta3YfzUTczCnUoi3nA2MBIkhyAmZ7UhOasCiXxks+36cMk/J+iOc1dcfEXxbNbv8m2h8uGhL3YxR39W776ReiRYF9tETJXSAxo1scwfDK8mOoz5ytrpXsop5c2c+4LtvP09EP/tGUcDrSo7W54TFRJ4Vg0juDj0Q9WLg8PTP+5Fkk/VYXmPQflv9jWpTzDvDKymgqMiZiXNQvZvfu1+6sGLGppDCpyYPD1+Mv/vJq9WBf51V/trnEQHFNfHoHPODz/GQJP16DilPOAB1AiHHpRMZz+U3h4RDBX1I/O1gWogBverRTXHm62OaUDGErO0XUwsldBrn4E2QFdFszN5Gk5r9m/duI/2q2/hNWUWC7pQigfq2ED+lP0UoB1+qYte0OLGwJKrZSY3qNJj0O95xMyGqCkklluvNmiN4LA4KxuDCI7AUzlGI6fwgJYGxzQjIzeyY8Uzr16qB8vvtA=</Output>
        <OutputHash xsi:type="xsd:string">877C40EB46C09F7C2066CADF3EEF4E12D2D5CE15</OutputHash>
        <OutputKey xsi:type="xsd:string"></OutputKey>
        <OutputKeyHash xsi:type="xsd:string"></OutputKeyHash>
        <OutputSecuence xsi:type="xsd:string">20170102112384225</OutputSecuence>
    </NS2:TECGIncomingResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I'm trying to extract `<Output>` and `<Error>` tags value using XSL template.
I have tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:value-of select="SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/NS2:TECGIncomingResponse/Output"/>
<xsl:value-of select="SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/NS2:TECGIncomingResponse/Output"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it throws an error. I think is not very complex! How can i get that result? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You forgot to define the prefix mapping for NS2: `xmlns:NS2="urn:unECGIncomingSoapGlobal"`

Comment: Thanks a lot @teppic !! Little mistake! It was helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:NS2="urn:unECGIncomingSoapGlobal">    
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/NS2:TECGIncomingResponse/Error"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/NS2:TECGIncomingResponse/Output"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That Worked for me!! I forgot to define the prefix mapping for NS2: `xmlns:NS2="urn:unECGIncomingSoapGlobal`